# App Video Preview recording dimensions

Tags: video, ios

How do you record App Preview videos for the new devices?

I have a 5S and when I record (on Yosemite) with Quicktime, the video's dimensions are 640 × 1136 - the size of the phone. Which is fine for the video for the (5 series, 4 inch).

But how do I record for the 6 (1134 x 750)  & 6+ (1920 x 1080)?

Can you use the Simulator? There is no mention of it. Surely we dont have to buy the devices...?